# Teamcity MSBuild Copy build output to new folder

Tags: deployment, msbuild, teamcity

I've managed to get Teamcity running and connecting into bitbucket and the final step I'd like would be to get the MVC 4 project copied into another folder on the server ready for an xcopy deployment onto a web host.

I'm using MSBUILD, as the build agent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preferred way is to use publishing targets in MSBuild.

1. Add new build step with runner type **MSBuild**
2. Set `Build file path` to your web project `csproj` file
3. Set `Target` to `Clean;Build;Publish`
4. Set `Command line parameters` to `/p:Configuration=Release;PublishDir=\\your\target\path`

Hope this helps.

Comment: How have you wired this up in teamcity? I'm unsure on the params sorry for the questions new to teamcity.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CommandLine buildrunner to xcopy. 
Personally I would not even copy the result to a different server.

For deployment I would have a deployment project in Teamcity that gets the required artifcat via wget from the Teamcity Rest-Api and uploads it to the hosting provider.
This can also be done in CommandLine  buildrunner.

Comment: "This can also be done in CommandLine buildrunner." I believe you it can be done, but how can it be done? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Under general settings

Click "Show advanced options"

Under Artifact Paths you can specify what you would like put under a new folder

```
**/* => target_directory
```

Or you can zip up your files and put under a new folder like this

```
**/* => newfolder/mypackage.zip
```

See more details here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2019.2/configuring-general-settings.html#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-ArtifactPaths